# Is there a big list of web proxy servers in JSON format or an other standard format

Tags: json, http-proxy

What I need is a very large list of web proxies in a format which can be easily parsed with a program (JSON for example).

My application will randomly choose a web proxy in the list and will use it to do some requests.

I don't think that this detail is important, but my application is coded with C#.

I already found some lists of proxies in txt file, but the quality is very low.

Comment: "Thumbs down" are not useful at all if you don't explain why the question is not good. Write a comment at least.

Comment: Your question is off-topic, since you are [asking "us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource".](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) The only reason it is not closed by now is that you placed a bounty on it - this enabled a technical protection against closure. After the bounty times out, it will be gone ...

Answer (score 2):

Here is a list of web proxies in JSON format: [link](http://pastebin.com/UN2Xa2hE) compiled from [source](https://incloak.com/proxy-list/?type=h).  Hope it helps.